# How to draw shape using xml in android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Need to draw the following circle , with the red colour shape using xml.

[image]

Is it possible to draw this using xml only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make circle using the following `XML` code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
<solid android:color="#c4bfbf"/>
</shape>
```

You can add the above circle as the background to a view, and on top of that view you could keep another view, which could be center vertical, and it's `XML` would be:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"  />
    <padding android:bottom="1dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="1dp"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: can you help me out here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412704/how-to-draw-a-dot-circle-inside-a-square-drawable-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412704/how-to-draw-a-dot-circle-inside-a-square-drawable-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

to draw circle programmatically you can use this way,this worked for me

```
ShapeDrawable biggerCircle= new ShapeDrawable( new OvalShape());
                biggerCircle.setIntrinsicHeight( 60 );
                biggerCircle.setIntrinsicWidth( 60);
                biggerCircle.setBounds(new Rect(30, 30, 30, 30));
                biggerCircle.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor(first));//give any color here
                holder.firstcolor.setBackgroundDrawable(biggerCircle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create the similar shape where an outer gray circle contains red circle inside. Here is the code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >
<solid android:color="#E84F3D" />
<stroke
    android:width="15dp"
    android:color="#BEBEBE" />

</shape>
```