# How to draw a dot circle inside a square drawable in android?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable, android-shapedrawable

I want a small dot inside a square button , this is what i have tried till now as answered by azizbekian:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="100dp" android:height="100dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#38b0ef"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="45dp"
        android:left="45dp"
        android:right="45dp"
        android:top="45dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#0c5069"/>
            <size android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#0c5069"/>
        </shape>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

The first image is what i have tried and the second image is what i want excluding the text.

[image: this is how it looks now]
[image: this is how i want excluding the text]

and also this code is the button to which i have to apply the drawable
there are seven such buttons in an horizontal linearlayout with weightsum:100 each button has weight 14

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/wed"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="35dp"
   android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
   android:background="@drawable/my_button_dot"
   android:text="WED"
   android:textAllCaps="true"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:textColor="#ffffff"
   android:layout_weight="15"/>
```

the dot does not appear in the background when this drawable is applied to the button, maybe because of the size of button and drawable i tried to adjust the size of drawable, but i just do not understand it and it did not work, how can i adjust it such that the dot appears in button background.

Comment: Why do you need `layer-list`? Why having ordinary oval shape won't do for you?

Comment: i want blue square with a small dot inside as in the second image..

Comment: Why not setting the dot as a separate `compoundDrawableBottom` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

first create color_circle in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">


  <solid android:color="#ffffff">


  </solid>

 <size
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp" />


</shape>
```

and then

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="148dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="WED" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/color_circle" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

i hope this is what you want

Answer (score 0):

This is

> ImageView has src to dotted.xml.

```
<ImageView
  android:layout_width="178.8dp"
  android:layout_height="178.8dp"
  android:src="@drawable/dotted"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:layerType="software" />
```

> ```
> add below to drawable/dotted.xml
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">
  <stroke
    android:color="@android:color/white"
    android:dashWidth="1px"
    android:dashGap="10px"
    android:width="6.6dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Indentation changes